# Can’t get the phpunit core test for WordPress to work

Tags: php, unit-testing, wordpress, phpunit

I’m trying to set up the test for the WordPress core to make sure that the plugin I’m developing dose’t break anything. But I’m having a problem which I really have no idea how to fix. I downloaded the files located at www.develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunc(I know I can use sub-version, but I’m having some troubles setting it up in phpStorm, so I’m focusing on this problem), and set everything up.
I get the tests running, but about half way through the tests, I get an error, which i have no idea where originates. It’s to long to post here, but it seems to repeate it self, so here is a a sample of the first lines

```
WordPress database error Table 'multipress_testc.wptests_4_options' doesn't exist for            
query INSERT INTO `wptests_4_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES   
('active_plugins', 'a:1:{i:0;s:9:\"hello.php\";}', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` 
= VALUES(`autoload`) made by PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main, PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run,  
PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun, PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run, 
PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run, PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest, 
PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run, PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run, 
PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare, PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest, 
ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs, Tests_MS->test_active_network_plugins, activate_plugin, 
update_option, add_option
```

The last errors i get is a php errors saying

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function to_array() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/(folder-name)/(wordpress root folder)/wp-includes/post.php on line 411

Fatal error: Call to a member function to_array() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/(folder-name)/(wordpress root folder)/wp-includes/post.php on line 411
```

The value of the non-object is bool(false)

I’m running the multisite tests.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this at [wordpress.se] or drop a line at [wp-hackers](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/).

Comment: `WordPress database error Table 'multipress_testc.wptests_4_options' doesn't exist` says that the table `multipress_testc.wptests_4_options` is missing in your DB. In most cases `$wpdb` returns false if a query fails, which in turn produces errors like `Fatal error: Call to a member function to_array() on a non-object` since the function expects an object but gets a bool(false). Check your DB tables.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was told that I should run the test agains a clear, empty database. Is this wrong? If it is, how I’m i supposed to set it up?